# Can foil strain gauges measure strain normal to the plane of the sensor?

Tags: measurements

I'm wondering if anyone in the community has experience with foil strain gauges used to measure strain components that are normal to the plane of the sensor? If the strain gauge were pressed between two large flat plates, for example, would there be enough deformation of the conductive path to cause a measurable change in resistance?

Comment: If you are allowed to take the plates apart you can use a contact pressure tape, e.g., http://www.sensorexpert.com/

Comment: That looks like a much simpler way to go. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, strain gauges are pasted on a surface and give indications about the in-plane strains. 
A Load cell is a device that uses strain-gauges  and can measure the *force* perpendicular to the surface. [Load cells in wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_cell)
Can you please describe what specifically do you want to measure?

Comment: We're trying to measure actual pressures across a matched mold surface, so we have to use transducers that have a thickness less than or equal to the intended part thickness (~0.090"). If there's a different type of sensor that would work better, I'd be very interested.

Comment: Strain gauge measures the condition of plane stresses not strain, because there is no normal stress acts on the surface upon which we attach the strain gauge.

Comment: Strain gauge measures strain, not stress. The stress is calculated from the strains and by knowing the Young modulus.